# How to override environment variables when running configure?

Tags: include, environment-variables, autotools, configure

In any major package for Linux, running `./configure --help` will output at the end:

```
Some influential environment variables:
      CC          C compiler command
      CFLAGS      C compiler flags
      LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
                  nonstandard directory <lib dir>
      CPPFLAGS    C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if you have
                  headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
      CPP         C preprocessor

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.
```

How do I use these variables to include a directory? I tried running `./configure --CFLAGS="-I/home/package/custom/"` and `./configure CFLAGS="-I/home/package/custom/"`, however these do not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not flags passed to configure. These are environment variables  you need to set. e.g. `export CFLAGS="-I foo"`.

Comment: However, you can also pass them as flags to configure.

Answer (score 7):

The variable you need to use for `-I` is `CPPFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`. (As it says right there in the help message you copied.) CPP stands for "C preprocessor", not C++. So:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-I/home/package/custom'
```