# MacOS compile error with clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Tags: c, macos, clang, openmp

I got stucked in error during installing IpOPT on MacOS Ventura 13.4.1.

I did `./configure` as instructed in [Ipopt Installation Instruction](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html#COMPILEINSTALL) and tried compiling via:

```
make
```

However, the following error occurred:

```
  ...
  CXXLD libipopt.la
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make[3]: *** [libipopt.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I've already installed `llvm` and `libomp` by following:

```
brew install llvm 
brew install libomp
```

I really can't get about solution.
Can anyone help me with this?

The following is the whole configure commmand line:

```
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether the compiler supports GNU Fortran 77... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking how to get verbose linking output from gfortran... -v
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of gfortran...  -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/13 -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/13/../../.. -lgfortran -lemutls_w -lquadmath
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... lower case, underscore, no extra underscore
checking whether gfortran understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0 file names to aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for file... file
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin22.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the g++ linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin22.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if gfortran PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin22.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: libtool version info: -version-number 3:14:13
configure: Assuming that CXXLIBS is -lc++.
configure: configuring doxygen documentation options
checking for doxygen... no
checking for latex... no
checking for dot... NO
checking for library containing cos... none required
checking for pkgconf... no
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16.0... yes: 0.29.2
configure: pkg-config path is "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:"
checking for LAPACK... yes: Accelerate framework (-framework Accelerate)
checking for package ASL... yes
checking for package Mumps... yes
checking for MPI_Initialized... no
checking for package HSL... yes
checking for function ma27ad_ in -L/usr/local/lib -lcoinhsl   ... yes
checking for function ma28ad_ in -L/usr/local/lib -lcoinhsl   ... yes
checking for function pardiso_ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function pardiso in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function PARDISO_ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function PARDISO in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function pardiso__ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function pardiso_ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function PARDISO__ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for function PARDISO_ in -framework Accelerate ... no
checking for library Spral with combined link and compile check... skipping (default)
checking size of int *... 8
checking for cmath... yes
checking for cfloat... yes
checking for cieeefp... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking for g++ options needed to detect all undeclared functions... none needed
checking for std::isfinite... yes
checking whether va_copy is declared... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking whether drand48 is declared... yes
checking whether rand is declared... yes
checking for std::srand... yes
checking whether feenableexcept is declared... no
checking for gcj... no
checking for guavac... no
checking for jikes... no
checking for javac... javac
checking if javac works... yes
checking if javac supports -h... yes
checking for javac... /usr/bin/javac
checking jni headers... /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/include
checking for jar... jar
checking for kaffe... no
checking for java... java
checking for javadoc... javadoc
checking whether the linear solver loader should be used... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for windows.h... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/ipopt.pc
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Apps/AmplSolver/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Apps/AmplSolver/ipoptamplinterface.pc
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/run_unitTests
config.status: creating doc/Doxyfile
config.status: creating examples/Cpp_example/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/recursive_nlp/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/hs071_cpp/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/hs071_c/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/ScalableProblems/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/C/1-skeleton/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/C/2-mistake/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/C/3-solution/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Cpp/1-skeleton/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Cpp/2-mistake/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Cpp/3-solution/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Matlab/1-skeleton/startup.m
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Matlab/2-mistake/startup.m
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Matlab/3-solution/startup.m
config.status: creating examples/hs071_f/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/hs071_f/hs071_f.f
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/1-skeleton/TutorialFortran.f
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/2-mistake/TutorialFortran.f
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/3-solution/TutorialFortran.f
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/1-skeleton/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/2-mistake/Makefile
config.status: creating tutorial/CodingExercise/Fortran/3-solution/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/hs071_java/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/ScalableProblems_java/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/src/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/AmplSolver/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/examples/parametric_cpp/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/examples/parametric_dsdp_cpp/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/sIPOPT/examples/redhess_cpp/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/RInterface/src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/Common/config.h
config.status: creating src/Common/config_ipopt.h
config.status: linking examples/hs071_cpp/hs071_main.cpp to test/hs071_main.cpp
config.status: linking examples/hs071_cpp/hs071_nlp.cpp to test/hs071_nlp.cpp
config.status: linking examples/hs071_cpp/hs071_nlp.hpp to test/hs071_nlp.hpp
config.status: linking examples/hs071_c/hs071_c.c to test/hs071_c.c
config.status: linking contrib/sIPOPT/examples/parametric_cpp/parametric_driver.cpp to test/parametric_driver.cpp
config.status: linking contrib/sIPOPT/examples/parametric_cpp/parametricTNLP.cpp to test/parametricTNLP.cpp

config.status: linking contrib/sIPOPT/examples/redhess_cpp/MySensTNLP.cpp to test/MySensTNLP.cpp
config.status: linking contrib/sIPOPT/examples/redhess_cpp/redhess_cpp.cpp to test/redhess_cpp.cpp
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: Configuration of Ipopt successful
```

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/ and then, you can easily use `gcc -o main -fopenmp main.c` and run `OpenMP` based code.

Comment: @Oo.oO although the suggestion to use gcc is good, the given link is irrelevant. Why manually installing an old gcc version instead of an up to date version with a package manager like brew or macports? Moreover the link focuses on Fortran coarrays, which definitely not needed by the OP.

Comment: Please show your full configure command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenMP on macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714019/openmp-on-macos-mojave)

Comment: @Richard Barber I tried that but cmake is not applied to mine

Comment: @PierU I only did ./configure without any options

Comment: You need those preprocessor flags.

Comment: @RichardBarber So, can I just add the corresponding flags to the Makefile?

Comment: @PierU - you are, most probably, completely right. However, with suggested setup, well how to put it simply, it just builds without any issues ;) And how about your setup. The ideal one ;)

Comment: @Axolotl I would recommend adding them to the `.configure` environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717623/how-to-override-environment-variables-when-running-configure

Answer (score 1):

Apple has explicitly disabled support for OpemMp. Here is the article. Instead, we can use using -Xclang flag. Please refer below

https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/

But, if you want to use it with llvm, you might want to include these flags.

```
CPPFLAGS += -Xclang -fopenmp
LDFLAGS += -lomp
```

source: https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/#do